# Contents of `Label` in `ListView` are not Showed

Tags: c#, maui

I would like to edit the MAUI initialized file to do the following

1. add an object to the BindingContext in MainPage.xaml.cs each time a Button is clicked
2. display the BindingContext using a ListView

In doing so, the above problem occurred. Specifically, the image below is what happened.

[image]

The code is as follows, we created `Meeting.cs` and `AllMeetings.cs` as Models.

`MainPage.xaml.cs`

```cs
namespace App.Views;

using App.Models;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int count = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new Models.AllMeetings();
    }

    private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count++;

        if (count == 1)
            CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
        else
            CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";

        SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);

        ((Models.AllMeetings)BindingContext).Add_Meeting(new Models.Meeting() { Name = "foo" });
    }
}
```

`MainPage.xaml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App.Views"
             x:Class="App.Views.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Meetings}" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

`AllMeetings.cs`

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace App.Models;

internal class AllMeetings
{
    public ObservableCollection<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Meeting>();

    public void Add_Meeting(Meeting meeting)
    {
        this.Meetings.Add(meeting);
    }

}
```

`Meeting.cs`

```cs
namespace App.Models;

internal class Meeting
{
    public string Name { get; set; };
}
```

When I wrote this code, no characters were output as shown in the above image, so the same thing happened when I changed the contents of `ListView` in `MainPage.xaml` as follows.

```xml
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Meetings}" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Label Text="hoge" />
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: I have tested your code with a new project on the android and windows. The labels will show the correct content.

Comment: Was the label's text color same as the label's background color? You can try to set `<Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor = "White"/>` to test.